# Access S/4 on-premise from local machine without cloud destination service

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk, sap-business-technology-platform

I'm trying to access our S/4 on-premise system without any cloud services involved.
I', connected to the VPN and can reach our S/4 system and successfully address the BP API service with Postman.

When I deploy my app, the whole thing works as well. However, I don't want to program blindly and start & test the whole thing from my local machine. Unfortunately it does not work...

> Failed to get 'destination' service credentials from VCAP_SERVICES variable: no service binding found for service plan '(any)'. Please make sure to correctly bind your application to a service instance of the destination service.

and

> Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.exception.TokenRequestFailedException: Failed to get destination service client identifier and secret. Please make sure to correctly bind your application to a destination service instance

Can I access the S4 directly with the cloud SDK, or do I need a destination service in the btp?

My application-local.yaml file looks like:

```
destinations:
  s4:
    name: s4
    authentication-type: BASIC_AUTHENTICATION
    url: 'https://ourS4URL'
    user: USER
    password: ZZZ
    trust-all-certificates: true
```

Just to test it, I try to read out all destinations, but even here I get directly the above mentioned errors:

```
ScpCfDestinationLoader load = new ScpCfDestinationLoader();
Try<Iterable<ScpCfDestination>> destinations = load.tryGetAllDestinations();
// sysout etc.
```

The only difference to the deployed version is, that I start the application.yaml with the profile "cloud", instead of the "locale" like here.
What have I forgotten? Or is it really not possible?

edit:
Thats how I use my service in the deployed version:

```
HttpDestination httpDestination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("s4").asHttp()
    .decorate(DefaultErpHttpDestination::new);

final BusinessPartnerService service = new DefaultBusinessPartnerService();
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are able to access the on-premise system directly, instead of making use of the Destination service you could choose to create a Destination programmatically and register it so that the `DestinationAccessor` is able to furnish the details of this destination. Please read more about this option [here](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/connectivity/destination-service#registering-destinations-at-runtime).

Alternatively, you can also set an environment variable for your destination: (Example is for Windows, please adapt according to your OS)

```
$destinations='[{name: "MyErpSystem", url: "https://URL", "username": "USER", "password": "PASSWORD"}]'
```

Both of these methods ensure that the `DestinationAcessor` returns a valid Destination (of your S/4 on-premise system).

Comment: Did not work, but I was able to connect to the BTP-Destination-Service via cf ssh. Now I can talk to our in prem service from my local dev.